# jQuery prevent default not working

Tags: jquery

I have a simple form in a php file:

```
<form class='loginForm' id='loginForm'>
    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='username' placeholder='email address'>
    <button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block' type='submit'>Login</button>
</form>
```

Im trying to stop the form submission by:

```
$("#loginForm").on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But its not stopping it, what am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: use jquery script after `<form>` declaration

Comment: Check your jquery is working fine or not ?

Comment: It works fine on snippet, make sure you are using jquery library.

Comment: Does the jQuery code gets loaded before your form and did you tried to use `$("#loginForm").submit(function...`?

Comment: add alert `alert('123');`  and check function is working or not

Comment: Just changed it, my jQuery code is in the footer now. But im loading the login form from an api, so it still gets loaded before the form. also added it in a document ready and added an alert, alert is not showing

Comment: wrap your code inside $(document).raady() to be safe that your function is loaded after the document is fully rendered.

$(function() { ... });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use event delegation when attaching events to content that loads after document ready.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('submit', "#loginForm", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<form class='loginForm' id='loginForm'>
    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='username' placeholder='email address'>
    <button class='btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block' type='submit'>Login</button>
</form>
```